# Streaming audio from remote service and play it in speakers

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, speaker, headphones

I have a streaming service running with help of `RTP Stream class`. I could able to stream audio from a remote IP. I have used wireshark to check the connection and it is receiving packets from the server. Now I would like to play the received audio in android speakers or headphones. I tried using `Mediaplayer class` but it seems something is missing. How can I proceed forward ?

```
public class audioService extends Service {

AudioStream audioStream;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
Context context;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    new Thread(new audioRunnable()).start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private class audioRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
        public void run() {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            AudioGroup audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
            audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_ECHO_SUPPRESSION);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(audioManager.STREAM_RING);
            InetAddress inetAddress;

            try {

                inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.0");
                audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddress);
                audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
                audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);
                InetAddress inetAddressRemote = InetAddress.getByName("192.00.00.00");
                audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, 8088);
                audioStream.join(audioGroup);

                // start the media player
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("10.0.0.0"));
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

}

Note: I have the permissions in Manifest files
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`

Comment: Please check which remote ip address you are streaming and from where you are reading the data from.